# Expose underlying file with pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I've been running some function, with pdb and a for loop, for some time. Since this time, I've modified the underlying file substantially.

Is there a way to print the file that PDB is running? I'm not even sure if it exists in the filesystem anymore (clearly I'm an ignoramus. Also, yes, it was a huge mistake to continue editing the file instead of committing or renaming)

I can use 'n' to print individual lines, but that's only within a scope that's a subset of the overall script. I.e., I want to print even the lines that have already been run

Comment: You may be able to decompile all the attributes of `globals()` that have `__module__` set to the name of the module you are interested in...

Comment: thanks - can you provide a reference or some search terms for how to do that? I've never dealt with either of those concepts